# Reshaping NumPy Array with Index Locations in Columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3 column numpy array, as follows

```
[0 0 'a'
 0 1 'b'
 1 0 'c'
 1 1 'd']
```

The first column contains the row index for the 3rd columns value, and the second column the column index. That is, the final output should be

```
['a' 'b'
 'c' 'd']
```

How can I use numpy to place the third columns values into a numpy array at the indices specified in the first two columns? In reality, my dataset is much larger (this is for HD imagery, a 13000 x 11000 pixel photograph, so efficiency is important (avoiding loops)).

Thanks!

Comment: Will the third column actually be a string? If so, your numpy matrix will be of mixed `dtype`s and will be of an `object` type. I've given an example with the third column replaced with numbers, but if you want strings, I can add a bit more info.

Comment: It is actually a number, I just used a string to better illustrate the problem, thinking solution would be the same. My mistake, and thanks!

Comment: No problem! I figured it might have been for the sake of demonstration! As long as the first 2 columns are converted to `int` they should be able to index the array fine ;) the third column just has to be able to be implicitly or explicitly cast to the numpy array `dtype` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to place the values in an empty instantiated array. Here's an example assuming the third column is actually numeric, with the values `[1, 3, 5, 7]`, and that your matrix is square (if it isn't you can change the shape of the empty matrix, as long as you can get the dimensions).

```py
ar = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 3, 5, 7]]).T
n = int(np.sqrt(ar.shape[0]))  # Assuming you have a square matrix
out = np.empty([n, n])  # Create a new array of the expected shape
row_idx = ar[:, 0]
col_idx = ar[:, 1]
out[row_idx, col_idx] = ar[:, 2]  # Put the data into the indexed locations
```

which returns:

```py
>> out
array([[1., 3.],
       [5., 7.]])
```

If your third column is actually a string, then it's a bit more tricky, as you have to specify the size of the string you want to handle when you instantiate the numpy array and also convert the index slices from `object` back to `int`.

---

EDIT: Additional info for string data.
If you are actually trying to put strings into a numpy array, you'll need to declare the size of expected string using the unicode string `dtype='U1'` kwarg to `np.empty`, where the number after `U` is the length of the character array.

```py
ar = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]).T
row_idx = ar[:, 0].astype(int)
col_idx = ar[:, 1].astype(int)
out = np.empty([2, 2], dtype='U1')  # Unicode string
out[row_idx, col_idx] = ar[:, 2]
```

which returns:

```py
>> out
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'd']], dtype='<U1')
```